# Any links / guidance on how to iterate and log raw pixels of an image using swift in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext, cgcontextdrawimage

I'm trying to work on raw pixels of an image using swift language in iOS development. My target is to iterate and log pixel values / color space information of image using CGContextDrawImage and CGContextRef methods. Like the output in attached screenshot. Can anyone guide me through this ? I so far haven't come across a solution.

[image]

Comment: Not a duplicate but the answer lies in that question I believe :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587792/apply-visual-effect-to-images-pixel-by-pixel-in-swift

Comment: I checked and studied more after that, but we would need CGContextDrawImage for drawing the image into the above graphics context right ? They have used CGDataProviderCreateWithData to read buffer of image. So after using data provider we can iterate the received pixels to print the above image in pixels ?